# Python "Else" statement always returns True

Tags: python, new-operator

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uexuk.png)

```
print("Hello World")
print("How're you?")
mood = input()
print("I'm " + mood + " too")
print("What's your name?")
name = input()
print(name + ". I really like that name!")
food = input("I really like pizza. Do you? Y/N ")
if food == 'y' or 'Y':
    print("Wow! " + name + ", you and I have a really similar taste in food, don't we? So what else do you like?")
elif food == 'n' or 'N':
    print("Oh, that's a shame. I was gonna treat us to a cheeky Papa Johns!")
else:
    print("Oh! Okay. Then what else do you like?")
other = input()
if other == 'liquorice' or 'Liquorice' or 'Brussels Sprouts' or 'brussels sprouts':
    print("Blegh! " + name + ", I respect you and all... but gross!")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mn9N.png)

I'm trying to make the program use the ELIF and ELSE outputs when I type in something other than Y or y (standing for yes). What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: can you please paste your code here.

Comment: Please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your syntax is not logically correct. Try `if food == 'y' or food == 'Y'`.  Similarly on the `elif`

Comment: Python is not English: `food in 'yY'`, or perhaps `food.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've solved the problem now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
if food =='y' or 'Y':
```

the python will return true all the time, you can test this:

```
if 'false':
    print('true')
```

To make it work,  replace `food =='y' or 'Y'` with either `food =='y' or food=='Y'` or as suggested by @Peter Wood, use the lower/upper of the `food`